# Average acceleration versus instantaneous acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Does instantaneous acceleration also changes when direction of velocity changes. I know average acceleration does change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instantaneous acceleration is the time derivative of the velocity vector:

$$ \vec{a} = \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} $$

If the velocity is changing then the acceleration will be non-zero.

Comment: John Rennie: "_The instantaneous acceleration is the time derivative of the velocity vector:_" -- Good enough, for the problem at hand. (How to determine and to compare "_velocity vector_" values as function of "_time_" is sure to come up elsewhere.) "_If the velocity is changing then the acceleration will be non-zero._" -- Not quite: If the values of (instantaneous) velocity are changing (are different) at different "instances" then the value of acceleration at some particular instance is **not necessarily** non-zero, nor even defined. (Or are you considering "v changing at an instant"??)

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to compare both is to invoke the definitions:
$${\vec a}_{\rm avg} = \frac{\Delta {\vec v}}{\Delta t}$$
and 
$${\vec a}_{\rm inst} = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta {\vec v}}{\Delta t} = \frac{d{\vec{v}}}{dt}$$

Graphically,

[image: accelaration]

and if you consider change over an infinitesimal time period $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, the same definition gives you the instantaneous accelaration.

Thus, in instantaneous acceleration, you are only shrinking the considered time interval to an infinitesimal. While that means that your instantaneous acceleration could have changes many times in the larger time duration $\Delta t$, on route to producing the net average acceleration, it doesn't change anything as far as the general conclusion of acceleration changing with a change in the velocity direction only, even if the magnitude is preserved. This originates from the fact that in both these definitions, acceleration is defined as the change in a vector, and  a vector can change even when its magnitude is held constant, via a change in its direction. For example, $v = 4$ units along x-axis, and $v = 4$ units along y-axis, are two different vectors.

Hope that helps.

---

{Image source = [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Acceleration_as_derivative_of_velocity_along_trajectory.svg/500px-Acceleration_as_derivative_of_velocity_along_trajectory.svg.png)}

Comment: The Dark Side: +1 (Clearly the best answer given here at the moment. Still consider correcting the spelling of "_anything as afar as_", replacing "_time period_" or "_time interval_" by "duration", and drawing a picture with the vector quantities denoted as $\vec v$ and $\vec a$, respectively (i.e. as in your text already) if and when MathJax drawing capability becomes available here at PSE.

Comment: @user12262 - Thanks. I have incorporated the first two corrections, but I'm not sure what to do about the third. I'll have to think.