# Can you use $a=$$\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ instead of $\frac{dv}{dt}$ to find instantaneous acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation

Can you use  $\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ instead of $\frac{dv}{dt}$ to find instantaneous acceleration?

Comment: By "using $\Delta$", do you mean taking actual differences instead of taking a derivative? Why would you think you can do that? What's the context here?

Comment: [Related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174091/average-acceleration-versus-instantaneous-acceleration?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, if you take the limit $\Delta t\to 0$.

Comment: @G. Smith, without the limit, i mean why can't we find the instantaneous acceleration if we are using the same equation but without the limit? For example like a=0.0000000000000002/0.0000000000000001=2

Comment: @Zheer, why do you want to use a finite difference calculation in place of a derivative?

Comment: *why can't we find the instantaneous acceleration if we are using the same equation but without the limit?* Because if you don’t take the limit there is nothing instantaneous about it. It’s the average acceleration over a finite time interval, and in general you will get a different value for different choices of $\Delta t$. It may, however, be an excellent approximation to the instantaneous acceleration for sufficiently small $\Delta t$.

Comment: @G. Smith Re. "It may, however, be an excellent approximation to the instantaneous acceleration for sufficiently small Δt". -- and this is the only way to do it on a digital computer since the word sizes are limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d$ is used to denote an infinitesimal, so in the case of velocity $\frac{dv}{dt}\bigr |_{t_0}$ would represent the instantaneous rate of change in velocity at $t_0$, which is the acceleration at $t_0$. $\Delta$ is usually used to represent larger change, they are equal if $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is constant, but otherwise they are generally not.

Comment: "otherwise they are generally not" do you mean that we can't use  Δ in  a=Δv/Δt  for infinitesimal change to find instantaneous acceleration?

Comment: You can think of $\frac{dv}{dt}$ as being $\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ when the "change" represented by $\Delta$ is infinitesimally small. If you look at any graph that is a curve you can't generally find the gradient using $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$, but you *can* find the instantaneous gradient at a point and this is written $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and has to be calculated at a point.

Comment: "you can't generally find the gradient using Δy/Δx" why can't we generally find the gradient if we can always have infinitesimally small change?

Comment: Because $\Delta y/\Delta x$ does not typical represent an infinitesimal change. Think of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as being $\Delta y/\Delta x$ in the *special case* where the change represented by $\Delta$ is infinitesimally small.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the title is no. The first equation only gives you the average acceleration for the time interval. The only situation where it equals the instantaneous acceleration is if velocity is a linear function of time.

Hope this helps

Comment: According to my knowledge the change in Δy/Δx can be infinitesimally small that it equals the same number as the slope so why is the answer is no?

Comment: @Zheer Sure, but you didn't say that. Besides, when you make it infinitely small it becomes the derivative, the second equation. That's essentially the definition of the derivative!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you do use it, implicitly, in the definition of the derivative. First replace the changes with small changes $${\Delta v\over \Delta t} \rightarrow {\delta v\over \delta t}$$
Then the derivative is defined by
$${dv\over dt} = \lim\limits_{\delta t \to 0} {\delta v\over \delta t}$$

And recalling the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit, this really just means that $\delta t$ is a finite amount of time so small that taking it any smaller does not make any practical difference to the result.